# The difference between suspend and suspendAll

Tags: scorm2004

What is the difference between suspend and suspendAll in SCORM 2004 3rd ED?
Can I suspend more than one activity in one session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SCORM 2004, "suspending" something indicates that you want to preserve it's state. Think of it conceptually as a pause button, a way to stop and come back to the same place later.

"Suspend" and "SuspendAll" are used in two different contexts. As you probably are aware by now, the SCORM run-time and SCORM sequencing books are separate but related.

"Suspend" is a concept from the run-time book (if I read and understand your question correctly). Setting cmi.exit to suspend indicates that you want to save this set of run-time data for the current SCO so that when the activity is relaunched the data will still be available.

"SuspendAll" is a concept from the sequencing book. It is a navigation request that indicates the learner wants to pause and exit the *entire activity tree*. When a suspendAll navigation request is processed, the activity tree state (the sequencing data) is preserved and when the course is relaunched, the learner will resume from the current activity.

Some other thing to note:

suspendAll is not related to the preservation of run-time data. If you issue a suspendAll navigation request, that won't in itself preserve the current activity's run-time data.

To confuse matters a bit further, there are two more ways the word "suspend" is used:

"The Suspended Activity" - The activity that was current when a suspendAll navigation request was issued. This is the activity that will be resumed when the course is relaunched.

"Suspended" - a property of every activity that indicates whether it was last exited in a suspended state.

So, to answer your second question, there can only be one "suspended activity" at any given time, but many activities can be "suspended".

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm still confused,

Comment: Thanks mike,
You mean "SuspendAll" freezes and saves the current situation for the whole course including tracking data for each activity. On resuming the course, all sequencing and tracking data is restored. On the other hand, the concept "Suspend" is in effect only if "cmi.exit" is set to "suspend" which tells the system to save only the tracking data for the current activity, but has nothing to do with sequencing data. 
Mike, what if I have two suspended activities (cmi.exit = suspend) and then the "SuspendAll" is called? Is tracking data for (both/none/current activity) preserved?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If you have two activities with cmi.exit = suspend, and then a SuspendAll is called, then the run-time data for both suspended activities will be preserved. The activity that was current when SuspendAll was called will be marked as "*the* suspended activity". When the course is resumed, "the suspended activity" will be the one that is launched first.